# `forwardRef` error when dynamically importing a module in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm trying to use forwardRef on an external component but `ref.current` is not the actual `ref`. Not sure if I'm missing something.

I'm doing:

```js
const Editor = dynamic(() => import("react-markdown-editor-lite"), {
  ssr: false
});

const ForwardedRefEditor = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Editor {...props} ref={ref} />
));

-----

const editorRef = useRef(null);
<ForwardedRefEditor
  ref={editorRef}
  value={content}
  onChange={({ text }) => setContent(text)}
/>
```

Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-benz-qh4ec?file=/pages/index.js:63-73

More info: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4957

Answer (score 15):

You need to wrap your component in a custom component.

### Using forwardRef:

Wrap your `Editor` component:

```
import React from "react";
import Editor from "react-markdown-editor-lite";

export default function WrappedEditor({ editorRef, ...props }) {
  return <Editor {...props} ref={editorRef} />;
}
```

And then import it dynamically:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useRef, useState, forwardRef } from "react";

const Editor = dynamic(() => import("../WrappedEditor"), {
  ssr: false
});

const ForwardRefEditor = forwardRef((props, ref) => 
  <Editor {...props} editorRef={ref}/>
)

export default function IndexPage() {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  console.log("editorRef", editorRef.current);

  return (
    <ForwardRefEditor
      ref={editorRef}
      value={content}
      onChange={({ text }) => setContent(text)}
    />
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-pine-b8f5z)

You can also use the [custom prop approach](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1a018a023347fe1c2476073330cc5509) without using `forwardRef`.

### Custom prop

Wrap your `Editor` component exactly as in the previous example:

```
import React from "react";
import Editor from "react-markdown-editor-lite";

export default function WrappedEditor({ editorRef, ...props }) {
  return <Editor {...props} ref={editorRef} />;
}
```

Pass the custom ref prop to the `Editor` component:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

const Editor = dynamic(() => import("../WrappedEditor"), {
  ssr: false
});

export default function IndexPage() {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  console.log("editorRef", editorRef.current);

  return (
    <Editor
      editorRef={editorRef}
      value={content}
      onChange={({ text }) => setContent(text)}
    />
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-jennings-cxll6)

Comment: But why? Is there any explanation on why a different approach is required in this case?

Comment: @jayarjo When a component is wrapped in next/dynamic the passed ref should be a ref to the imported component, not an instance of nossr.